# How do I make a MacBook a trusted device so that it can receive Apple ID verification codes?

Tags: icloud, security, apple-id

I have a new MacBook Pro and I want to make it a trusted device so that it can receive Apple ID verification codes. My old MacBook Pro and my iPad are trusted devices but I am unable to make the new one a trusted device for my Apple ID.  I am logged into iCloud on both devices with the same account.  I can locate the new MacBook with the "Find My Mac" feature on icloud.com.

Both MacBooks are running Mojave 10.14.5

Comment: Hey, Welcome to Apple.SE! Go to iCloud settings-> account details on your older Mac and click on the icon of newer Mac. What does it say?

Comment: "A trusted device is an iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch with iOS 9 and later, or a Mac with OS X El Capitan and later that you've already signed in to using two-factor authentication. It’s a device we know is yours and that can be used to verify your identity by displaying a verification code from Apple when you sign in on a different device or browser." Have you signed into the newer MacBook using two factor authentication?